# Let's patch up the [patch] tag!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

I think the [patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch) should be split into two tags: [patch-panel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch-panel) and something to refer to patching a computer, perhaps [software-patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/software-patch) would be a good name (I'm open to other options, though). Or, [patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch) could refer to software patches, and a new tag, [patch-panel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch-panel) is made for rack-mounted patch panels.

Here's my thoughts: Looking at [the first few pages of questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch?tab=votes&pagesize=30) for it, it refers to one of two things: patch panels (like for a server rack) and patching a computer (applying an update to fix something). The highest voted questions are about software patches, but there are also [some questions about patch panels](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpatch%5dpatch%20panel). Both are on-topic here... but they are two different things. The [patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch) tag currently has no usage guidance, so a new tag should get some.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a widely used tag, getting under 120 questions after 12 years. But the confusion in there is clear. I'm fine with weeding it, and sorting what's in there between maybe [patch-cable](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch-cable) and [software-patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/software-patch). This kind of mass retagging tends to dominate the front page for a bit when we do it.

That said, I can set a tag-wiki for [patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch) to indicate what kind of patch we're talking about.

---

After digging through the tag, this is what I found

- 93 questions relating to software or hardware patch management.
- 7 questions relating to patch-panels and related
- 1 question directly about patch-cables.

Given this, I'm fine with doing the following:

- Retagging the 8 other questions into a new [patch-panel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch-panel)
- Create a new tag for [software-patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/software-patch) and set the tag wiki to indicate what it is for.
- Merge the [patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/patch) tag into [software-patch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/software-patch) and create a synonym.